# JSON.parse not working

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON returned by a post request. I have the following code:

```
response = RestClient.post "http://localhost:4567", request.body.read,:content_type => :json, :accept => :json
result = JSON.parse('#{response.body}')
```

It's giving me the following error:

```
JSON::ParserError - 757: unexpected token at '#{response.body}':
```

I have checked that `response.body` returns correct JSON. If I copy the content of the JSON and paste it into `JSON.parse` it works perfectly. However when I use the variable it does not work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to fix it to make the parse work?

Comment: Can you show what `response.body` looks like?

Comment: @Atri it's too long to fit here. {
  "age_result": [
    {
      "column_id": [
        "B01001003", 
        "B01001027"
      ], 
      "name": "Under 5 years", 
      "number": [
        6774.0, 
        6416.0
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "column_id": [
        "B01001004", 
        "B01001028"
      ], 
      "name": "5 to 9 years", 
      "number": [
        5981.0, 
        6470.0
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "column_id": [
        "B01001005", 
        "B01001029"
      ]
} This is part of it.

Comment: @JackLi check my answer if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're getting down votes because you didn't ask a good question. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]".

Comment: "`unexpected token at '#{response.body}'`" JSON is telling you exactly what the problem was, that the input made no sense. But *WHY* are you trying to embed a string into another string forcing it to be interpolated? Don't do that, simply put the string variable in as the parameter. `JSON.parse(response.body)`.

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes do not expand interpolation. `JSON.parse(response.body)` or `JSON.parse("#{response.body}")` shall work.

Comment: JSON.parse(response.body) does not work. It's telling me:ERROR TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String. I used is_a? to check if response.body is a string and the output is true.

Comment: @JackLi use `response.body.to_s` if `response.body` is an Array.

Comment: @Atri response.body is a string. I checked with is_a?

Comment: @JackLi can you show the content of `response.body` by printing it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that `response.body` is a String, you can do `JSON.parse(response.body)`. You don't need to interpolate it.

According to the example you gave in the comment, it works fine:

```
2.1.2-perf :007 > s =  '{ "age_result": [ { "column_id": [ "B01001003", "B01001027" ], "name": "Under 5 years", "number": [ 6774.0, 6416.0 ] }, { "column_id": [ "B01001004", "B01001028" ], "name": "5 to 9 years", "number": [ 5981.0, 6470.0 ] }] }'
 => "{ \"age_result\": [ { \"column_id\": [ \"B01001003\", \"B01001027\" ], \"name\": \"Under 5 years\", \"number\": [ 6774.0, 6416.0 ] }, { \"column_id\": [ \"B01001004\", \"B01001028\" ], \"name\": \"5 to 9 years\", \"number\": [ 5981.0, 6470.0 ] }] }"
2.1.2-perf :008 > JSON.parse(s)
 => {"age_result"=>[{"column_id"=>["B01001003", "B01001027"], "name"=>"Under 5 years", "number"=>[6774.0, 6416.0]}, {"column_id"=>["B01001004", "B01001028"], "name"=>"5 to 9 years", "number"=>[5981.0, 6470.0]}]}
```